# Possible to do SQL CALL in TCL?

Tags: sql, tcl, call

is it somehow possible, to execute a SQL CALL in TCL?
I can successfully do SELECTs but i can't do CALLs.

My code aus so far:

```
package require mysqltcl
set m [mysqlconnect -user myuser -password mypassword -host myhost]
mysqluse $m mydatabase
set s [mysqlsel $m {SELECT * FROM artikelstamm LIMIT 10} -flatlist]
mysqlclose $m
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried putting a CALL in the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution.
In the mysqlconnect statement, you have to add the the parameter "-multistatement true"

mysqlexec $m {call pr_myprocedure('$artikelnummer')}

works fine for me.